# Parsing DBpedia JSON from localhost extraction server in java when the schema isn't known

Tags: java, json, parsing, web-scraping

This is probably a quick answer to a very novice question. I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to get JSON text dbpedia extraction server running from a localhost. The server is running fine, I followed the [official instructions](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Documentation). 
[image: dbpedia extraction result in JSON]

I have read the other StackOverflow questions about parsing JSON in java and what I am having trouble understanding is how to parse the JSON when the schema or structure is unknown.

For example in my code I try to grab the JSON from localhost and put it into a java object. But all the examples of parsing JSON online use a predesigned java object and all the JSON keys are mapped to an object's fields. (ie Employee class: name,job,email,id,phone)

```
String sURL = "http://localhost:9999/server/extraction/en/extract?title=" + wikipage + "&revid=&format=rdf-json&extractors=custom"; //just a string

URL url = new URL(sURL);
Reader pageReader = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

Gson g = new Gson();
JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
jr.setLenient(true);

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //convert the input stream to a json element
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //may be an array, may be an object.
```

I now have this "json object" for the film "Blue Velvet" I can parse/iterate with jr.hasNext() or  rootobj.getAsJsonArray().
**Am I going about this correctly?**

I feel like I am reinventing the wheel. **Is there a standard way of parsing DBpedia JSON objects in Java?**

Comment: I found this site with some native code examples for Java. 
http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) JSON library allows you to parse incoming JSON into a Map. If the keys and values of the JSON can be of any type,  then you need to use `Map<Object, Object>`, which is a bit cumbersome, but anyways this should work:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<Object, Object> parsedJSON =  mapper.readValue(incomingJSON,
                        mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
                          LinkedHashMap.class,
                          Object.class, 
                          Object.class));
```